# Taking last 7 days average; but factor in the number of days available

Tags: sql

I'm having a bit of trouble working with windowing and partitions in GoogleSQL.

My script currently takes the revenue of the last 7 days by category and class:

```
    SELECT 
       date_id,
       category,
       class,
       revenue as revenue_usd,
       SUM(revenue)
          OVER(PARTITION BY product_area, product_group
          ORDER BY  date_id 
          RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 7 as l7d_avg_revenue_usd
    FROM
       (
       SELECT 
      date_id,
      category,
      class,
      SUM(revenue_usd_fx) as revenue
    FROM
      revenue_table
    WHERE  
        date_id BETWEEN DATE('2021-01-01') AND DATE('2021-03-31')
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
  )
```

However the problem with my script is that, for date 2021-01-01, it will still take the revenue of the date, and still divide it by 7.

For date_ids that are < 7 days in based on the availability in the database, how do i take an average of whatever days that have passed so far?

(E.g. 2021-01-01 will take an average of 1 day, 2020-01-03 will take an average of 3 days, and anything after 2021-01-07 will take an average of 7 days)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AVG()` instead of `SUM()`:

```
   AVG(revenue) OVER (
       PARTITION BY product_area, product_group
       ORDER BY  date_id 
       RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
      ) as l7d_avg_revenue_usd
```

Comment: Wow that was embarassing, why didn't I even think of that! Thank you!